# Search through list of maven archetypes in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, project

I am trying to create `maven` project in intellij idea. There is a huge list of archetypes on *New project* form. For example, I
do not know exact archetype name, but I want to create project in some specific area. Let's say it is a spark scala project. So, I would like to search occurencies of words *scala* and/or *spark* through the list of archetypes and figure out is there any suitable archetype. However, there is not search option for this list. Nevertheless, how I can search through the local list of archetypes?

Answer (score 1):

Just start typing the keyword you want to search at the top left will appear message "Search for "keyword" you entered".